# AngularJS form wizard save progress

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service in AngularJS that generates all the steps needed, the current state of each step (done, current, show, etc) and an associated directive that actually implements the service and displays the data of the service. But, there are 2 steps that are divided in 4 and 3 steps each:

- Step one

  - Discounts
  - Activities
  - Duration
  - Payment Length
- Step two

  - Identification
  - Personal data
  - Payment

How can I "save" the state of my form in case the person leaves the site and comes back later? Is it safe to use localStorage? I'm no providing support for IE6 or 7. I thought of using cookies, but that can end up being weak (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either local storage or cookies should be fine. I doubt this will be an issue, but keep in mind that both have a size limit. Also, it goes without saying that the form state will only be restored if the user returns on the same browser, and without having deleted cookies / local storage.

Another option could be to save the information server side. If the user is signed in, you can make periodic AJAX calls with the data and store the state on the server. When the user finishes all steps, you can make an AJAX call telling the server to delete any saved data it might have. This allows you to restore state even if the user returns on a different browser, as long as he is signed in.

Regardless of what direction you go with this, you can use jQuery's [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to serialize the form into a string and save it using your choice of storage.

Comment: isn't making AJAX calls for form state/progress not very "angular way"-y?

Comment: That's not true at all. I'm assuming you already have an end-point on your server where the user submits the form via a POST request. Modify that end-point to handle `PUT` requests as well, and use that to save state. If you have a custom Angular service, `$save()` is already implemented for you.